# VSCode disable large folders warning

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable the *"To enable project-wide JavaScript/TypeScript language features, exclude large folders with source files that you do not work on."* warning as it is displayed on each opening of files? I have configured jsconfig.json excluding folders such as node_moduels, but my source files are in the range of thousands.
I couldnt find such option in the preferences so I guess it is a typescript option? Im using vscode 1.14.1 and ts 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31188) use this glob pattern

> **/some_dir_like_node_modules/*

or it wont be detected and vscode will look into it.